# Using ChoETL to print CSV file returns values to Console as "dynamic"

Tags: c#, .net-core, choetl

Hi I am very new to C# and have to turn in a module for integration testing tomorrow. I was trying an easy and expidient way to read CSV files and stumbled on ChoETL:
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1145337/Cinchoo-ETL-CSV-Reader?msg=5847644#xx5847644xx

Following their first example, I tried to run the code:

```
using ChoETL;
using System;

foreach (dynamic rec in new ChoCSVReader("Emp.csv")
    .WithFirstLineHeader())
{            
    Console.WriteLine($"Id: {rec.Id}");
    Console.WriteLine($"Name: {rec.Name}");
}
```

When I run it, I get the ouput:

```
Id: 1
Name: dynamic
Id: 2
Name: dynamic
Id: 3
Name: dynamic
```

Instead of:

```
Id: 1
Name: Tom
Id: 2
Name: Carl
Id: 3
Name: Mark
```

WHy is this? And what is rec being turned to at runtime? I don't know anythnig about dynamic types

I ran this on a Console project on NetCore 5.0 on VS2019

Answer (score 0):

It is bug in the recent package (v1.2.1.30). Alternatively in order to run the sample successfully by doing as below

```
foreach (dynamic rec in ChoCSVReader.LoadText(csv).WithFirstLineHeader())
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Id: {rec.Id}");
    Console.WriteLine($"Name: " + rec["Name"]);
}
```

**UPDATE:**

This issue is fixed and pushed to nuget with v1.2.1.32 and give it try.

**Sample fiddle**: https://dotnetfiddle.net/REcRCc